# What is the weight of a single human sperm (spermatozoon) compared to a single human egg

Tags: human-biology, cell-biology, sexual-reproduction

While the difference in dimension is well covered, I have been unable to find the mass measurements of each.

Comment: Hey tohster! What attempts to answer this question have you already taken? We ask that all question posters here attempt to search for an answer to their own question and explicitly indicate what research they've already done, what they learned, and what is still confusing or unknown to them. Our goal is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way :). Please take a moment to edit your post with this additional detail, and it will likely be received more positively by our community. Thanks!

Comment: OK. That is new. I'm a member of quite a few stackexchange sites and I've not seen a requirement to document what efforts the user has gone through to answer the question. I used reasonable efforts to search online for an answer but was unable to find one, which is why I made the effort to post the question here so that others do not have to go through the same process.